# How do I copy text from one cell into all empty cells in the same column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the text contents of a given cell, such as A3, into all empty cells in column A. But I do not want to overwrite the contents in column A that already have data in them. The empty cells are not separated equally; some are 3 rows apart, some are 4, some are 7, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would take each cell in any group of selected cells, check to see if it has any contents, and if it is empty then fill it with the contents that are in cell A3.  Otherwise, it just moves on to the next cell in the selection.

```
Sub foo()

    'you can replace Selection with any kind of range -- Range("A1:A100") for instance.
    For Each c In Selection
        If c.Value = "" Then c.Value = Range("A3").Value

    Next c

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Good luck, hope it helps